# Settings for job setup of Valgrind plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, valgrind

Probably this is a basic query, but I am facing issues with it and cannot find a solution anywhere so..

I have two projects- one for android, other for iOS.
I need to setup valgrind jobs(run and publish) for both in Jenkins. My settings is causing 'no errors' in Valgrind results, hence it must definitely be wrong. I am unable to find documentation for this jenkins plugin, so I am shooting arrows in dark (and failing).

My settings for Valgrind plugin in Jenkins are(for android):
Cant load image as insufficient reputation :(

1. Run Valgrind

   ```
   Executable Include Pattern  ${PROGRAM_NAME}
   Working Directory   ${PROGRAM_DIR}
   Output Directory    ${PROGRAM_DIR}/ValgrindResults
   File Ending .memcheck
   ```

   In `Executable Include Pattern`, I have tried for `*.apk` (This is android project), but with same result.
2. Publish settings

   ```
   Report Pattern: *.memcheck
   ```

   <sup>(Other fields are irrevelant for basic memcheck test, as per my understanding)</sup>

My project definitely has multiple leaks, hence valgrind showing 'no errors' is unacceptable.

Any help/ links for better understanding/ example snapshots of settings would be welcome..

Comment: try change report pattern to ${PROGRAM_DIR}/ValgrindResults/*.memcheck

Comment: Try `**/*.memcheck`.